# Change panda DataFrame into paragraph with a certain format

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
# print dataframe.
df
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTtk6.png)

I wanted to change this dataframe to a text with certain format like:

" Here is the name and age Data:
Tom 10
Nick 15
Juli 14
Thank you for your request"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.capitalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html) and join values of `Age` converted to strings:

```
df['new'] = df['Name'].str.capitalize() + ' ' + df['Age'].astype(str)
print (df)
   Name  Age      new
0   tom   10   Tom 10
1  nick   15  Nick 15
2  juli   14  Juli 14
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df['Name'].str.capitalize().str.cat(df['Age'].astype(str), sep=' ')
```

If need loop by values:

```
s = df['Name'].str.capitalize() + ' ' + df['Age'].astype(str)

for v in s:
    print (v)
Tom 10
Nick 15
Juli 14
```

Comment: How do I print every row of 'new columns' into a separate lines??

Comment: @DavinTjandra - added to answer.